# Waiting for all functions and requests to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I've got some code that takes in an array of strings of the modules I wish to load

**script.js**

```
moduleLoader.load([
    'mainModule',
    'aboutUsModule',
    'featuresModule',
    'messageModule'
]);
```

The `moduleLoader.load` function does an `$.each` loop on the array and then proceeds to get the required information about each module.

**moduleLoader**

```
var load = function (modules) {
    $.each(modules, function (index, module) {
        getConfig(module);
    });
};
```

**getConfig**

```
var getConfig = function (module) {
    $.get(module + '/config.json').done(function (config) {
        console.log(config);
        getData(config);
    }).fail(function () {
        console.error('Couldn\'t find a config file for module: ' + module);
        return 0;
    });
};
```

Then you can see in the `getConfig` callback that it proceeds to get data, which is also async, and then it has two more steps after that which is async.

So it's basically callback inside callback inside callback... etc..

Just that I divided it into functions so that it looks a bit nicer.

Now I can get all the info, but it loads differently every time, so is it possible to know when all the ajax requests are done, and then do something?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the jQuery function `$.when()` that does exactly what you need:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

To make your code work you can refactor a bit:

```
var XHRs = [];

var load = function (modules) {
  $.each(modules, function (index, module) {
    XHRs.push(getConfig(module));
  });
};

$.when(XHRs).then(function() {
  // do something
});
```

And also your `getConfig()` function should return the `$.get`. This works because $.ajax in jQuery creates a Deferred object that actually lets you chain your functions or make them wait each other.

For future reference:
https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/

Comment: Then you have a global `XHRs` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize promise chaining and group them all together and do something when they are all done (kind of like this):

```
var load = function (modules) {
    var promises = modules.map(getConfig);

    // can use $.when or Promise.all here
    $.when.apply($, promises).then(function () {
         // do something when all done
    });
};

var getConfig = function (module) {
    // $.get returns a jqXHR which is "thennable"
    return $.get(module + '/config.json').then(function (config) {
        console.log(config);
        // if this also returns a promise then it will
        // wait till this one is done as well in the promise chain
        return getData(config); 
    }, function () {
        console.error('Couldn\'t find a config file for module: ' + module);
        return 0;
    });
};
```

Comment: What if at least one request failed? I guess it would make more issues but just saying...

Comment: @A.Wolff could be the 2nd fn into the then of the `$.when`

Comment: I just see OP asked for `when all the ajax requests are done`, so in fact your answer would work as expected. I was more wondering about using `always()` isntead of `then(successHandler)` but like i just said, forget my first comment ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you have no other pending ajax requests, then use relevant global ajax event [ajaxStop](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/):

```
$( document ).one('ajaxStop', function() {
  // all ajax requests has finished
});
```

Comment: But then when you stop using jquery it is all broke ;-)